# Which answer should be the accepted answer for this question

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I asked [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918834) a few days back. It had one answer that was correct but was not so relevant to what was asked (The person wrote something he used in Ember but not React).

So that answer guided me and I easily found a "correct" solution relevant to React and I posted the answer, so that someone visiting the question in future in reference to React can easily find the answer.

Now I am confused, which answer to mark as "accepted" answer, since I obviously referenced an answer before posting my own.

Moderators? Suggestions?

Note: Let me know if my answer does not add anything useful to page, I will remove it.

Comment: It's entirely up to you. You could reasonably do either. Do whatever you feel more comfortable with is probably best.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer should be the one that best answers the question asked.

You say that the first answer did not answer the question asked - it was the wrong framework. So it would be a bit strange to mark that as the accepted answer, but you could do so if you wanted.

I hope that the answer that you wrote yourself does actually answer the question you asked. In which case, marking it the accepted answer is the right thing to do, to help guide future readers with the same problem, to the effective solution

Comment: @Akshay You could include in your answer a link to the other answer that helped you: *Thanks to [X's answer] I found out a way to actually do this in React:*. You can use the *share* link below answers to obtain a clickable link.